# loss function with distinct weight for every input

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I want to design my custom loss function, which not only contains two input (y_real and y_pred), but I do not know if I can do it and how.

I have went through the answers about loss function, all of them only input  y_real and y_pred.

But in my projects, the loss of true and false prediction are various in cases, such that X1 with (loss_T1,loss_F1), X2 with (loss_T2, loss_F2).

So for my loss function, I need to input four variables (y_real,y_pred,loss_T,loss_F). The loss_T,loss_F are inside X (each row of my data) as one of features.

feature1    feature2    feature3    Loss_T  Loss_F  y
X1
X2
X3

Is there way I can do that?

Thanks to your good contributions.

Comment: Do you mean you need different weights for different samples (a whole vector for example) of different or different weights for different attributes? (elements of a vector).

Comment: May be try and come up with a mathematical formula for your loss?

Comment: if loss_T and Loss_F are features as you say, feed their values to some placeholders and use basic mathematical operations provided by tensorflow to build your loss function (like tf.add(x,y), tf.sub(x,y), tf.square(x), tf.reduce_sum(x) etc... ). Tensorflow would take care of backpropagation or other updates.

Comment: @maz different weights for different samples

Comment: @kaufmanu I can write a new loss function for it, but I need input loss for every sample, I do not know how to pass parameters in this cases.

Comment: @rajat from all examples I have read, loss function can only input y_true and y_pred. Even if I write a new loss function, the framework of TF won't pass the weight for every sample. The most relevant case is https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/2115 . But it also fix the weight by partial. If I am wrong, could you show me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tensorflow API at a lower level can work for you. For example, `Optimizer.optimize_loss` takes a loss tensor, which is just the output of the loss function, and minimizes it. So if you use `optimize_loss` diretly you can build your loss function in any complicated way you would like.

Comment: I try this way as you suggest. When I use if-else in the loss function, it reports bugs that no gradients provided for any variable. Anyway to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried using `tf.cond` instead of if-else? If-else is not supported by the tensorflow automatic differentiation.